# How to make ajax call on end of each block with infinite scrolling in ag-grid?

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, infinite-scroll, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid with angular 4. 
I am using infinite scrolling as the rowModelType. But since my data is huge, we want to first call just 100 records in the first ajax call and when the scroll reaches the end, the next ajax call needs to be made with the next 100 records? How can i do this using ag-grid in angular 4.

This is my current code

table-component.ts

```
export class AssaysTableComponent implements OnInit{
 //private rowData;
 private gridApi;
 private gridColumnApi;
 private columnDefs;
 private rowModelType;
 private paginationPageSize;
 private components;
 private rowData: any[];
 private cacheBlockSize;
 private infiniteInitialRowCount;
 allTableData : any[];

 constructor(private http:HttpClient, private appServices:AppServices) {
   this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Date/Time",
    field: "createdDate",
    headerCheckboxSelection: true,
    headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
    checkboxSelection: true,
    width: 250,
    cellRenderer: "loadingRenderer"
  },
  {headerName: 'Assay Name', field: 'assayName', width: 200},
  {headerName: 'Samples', field: 'sampleCount', width: 100}

];

this.components = {
  loadingRenderer: function(params) {
    if (params.value !== undefined) {
      return params.value;
    } else {
      return '<img src="../images/loading.gif">';
    }
  }
};
this.rowModelType = "infinite";
//this.paginationPageSize = 10;
this.cacheBlockSize = 10;
this.infiniteInitialRowCount = 1;

//this.rowData = this.appServices.assayData;
 }

 ngOnInit(){
 }

 onGridReady(params) {
   this.gridApi = params.api;
   this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
//const allTableData:string[] = [];

//const apiCount = 0;
//apiCount++;
console.log("assayApiCall>>",this.appServices.assayApiCall);
const assaysObj = new Assays();
assaysObj.sortBy = 'CREATED_DATE';
assaysObj.sortOder = 'desc';
assaysObj.count = "50";

if(this.appServices.assayApiCall>0){
  console.log("this.allTableData >> ",this.allTableData);
  assaysObj.startEvalulationKey = {
  }
}

this.appServices.downloadAssayFiles(assaysObj).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    if (response.length > 0) {
      var dataSource = {

        rowCount: null,
        getRows: function (params) {
          console.log("asking for " + params.startRow + " to " + params.endRow);
          setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("response>>",response);
            if(this.allTableData == undefined){
              this.allTableData = response;
            }
            else{
              this.allTableData = this.allTableData.concat(response);
            }
            var rowsThisPage = response.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
            var lastRow = -1;
            if (response.length <= params.endRow) {
              lastRow = response.length;
            }
            params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
          }, 500);
        }
      }
      params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
      this.appServices.setIsAssaysAvailable(true);
      this.appServices.assayApiCall +=1;
    }
    else{
      this.appServices.setIsAssaysAvailable(false)
    }
  }
)
 }
}
```

I will need to call this.appServices.downloadAssayFiles(assaysObj) at the end of 100 rows again to get the next set of 100 rows.

Please suggest a method of doing this.

Edit 1:

```
    private getRowData(startRow: number, endRow: number): Observable<any[]> {
    var rowData =[];
    const assaysObj = new Assays();
    assaysObj.sortBy = 'CREATED_DATE';
    assaysObj.sortOder = 'desc';
    assaysObj.count = "10";
    this.appServices.downloadAssayFiles(assaysObj).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (response.length > 0) {
          console.log("response>>",response);
          if(this.allTableData == undefined){
            this.allTableData = response;
          }
          else{
            rowData = response;
            this.allTableData = this.allTableData.concat(response);
          }
          this.appServices.setIsAssaysAvailable(true);
        }
        else{
          this.appServices.setIsAssaysAvailable(false)
        }
        console.log("rowdata>>",rowData);

      });
    return Observable.of(rowData);
  }

  onGridReady(params: any) {
    console.log("onGridReady");
    var dataSource = {
      getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
        this.info = "Getting datasource rows, start: " + params.startRow + ", end: " + params.endRow;
        console.log(this.info);
        this.getRowData(params.startRow, params.endRow)
          .subscribe(data => params.successCallback(data));

      }
    };
    params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
  }
```

Result 1 : The table is not loaded with the data. Also for some reason the service call this.appServices.downloadAssayFiles is being made thrice . Is there something wrong with my logic here.

Comment: Please put your logic in a stackblitz demo so others can more easily help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example of doing exactly this on the ag-grid site: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/.

How does your code currently act? It looks like you're modeling yours from the ag-grid docs page, but that you're getting all the data at once instead of getting only the chunks that you need.

Here's a stackblitz that I think does what you need. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-infinite-scroll-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts

In general you want to make sure you have a service method that can retrieve just the correct chunk of your data. You seem to be setting the correct range of data to the grid in your code, but the issue is that you've already spent the effort of getting *all* of it.

Here's the relevant code from that stackblitz. `getRowData` is the service call that returns an observable of the records that the grid asks for. Then in your subscribe method for that observable, you supply that data to the grid.

```
private getRowData(startRow: number, endRow: number): Observable<any[]> {
  // This is acting as a service call that will return just the
  // data range that you're asking for. In your case, you'd probably
  // call your http-based service which would also return an observable
  // of your data.
  var rowdata = [];
  for (var i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
    rowdata.push({ one: "hello", two: "world", three: "Item " + i });
  }
  return Observable.of(rowdata);
}

onGridReady(params: any) {
  console.log("onGridReady");
  var datasource = {
    getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
      this.getRowData(params.startRow, params.endRow)
                .subscribe(data => params.successCallback(data));
    }
  };
  params.api.setDatasource(datasource);

}
```

Comment: Please check edits for my updates with suggestions from you